# Is there a console to use Android api on a device?

Tags: android

I'm a developer (Rails & iOS) and I have no experience in Android.
I have an Android smartphone and I want to get somne info about the cameras inside.
Is there a way to use the api on the device directly? On Rails I can use console, with Android can I connect the smartphone in developer mode to my PC and using the api like these?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras()

Comment: There is `adb` utility which gives access to connected android device console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ADB](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/adb.html) to send commands to a device. You can also use `"adb shell ..."` to send bash commands. That said, the docs you are looking at, are about the Java API which is not available via ADB.

If you want to explore the Java API, you'll have to make a whole app in order to do so. The good thing is that Google just released [Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run), so making changes and checking how they behave on the app is a lot faster now.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand something.